# Cursor movement related tput commands under zsh: can the 'clear' behavior be configured?

Tags: zsh, termcap, tput

Using the [`zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/) shell, I've noticed a difference in the behavior of the [`tput`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tput%201) command compared to `bash`. For instance With `zsh`, if you have many things output to a terminal emulator window and you're at the "bottom", if you do `tput cup 1`, you go back up and everything below is cleared. With `bash` the output remains and is not cleared (on my setup). This comparison is valid for every terminal capability that moves the cursor around (cuu, cud, sc & rc, home, etc.).

Do you have any control over that behavior in `zsh` i.e. not clearing? I'm looking at the possible [options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options-Index.html#Options-Index-1_pg_letter-A), but there's lots of things... If you cannot alter the behavior, can you use some other command which doesn't behave like such?

Comment: BTW, zsh has a builtin command for `tput` (`echoti`, and `echotc` like in tcsh) and also a special associative array (`$terminfo`) with the capabilities. `print -rn $terminfo[home]`, `echoti cup 1 1`. See also the `zsh/curses` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` outputs its completions below the prompt, so it makes sure that area is clear.

I don't think you can disable it. However you can tell `zsh` that the escape sequence to clear until the end of the screen is the empty string.

```
infocmp -x | sed 's/ed=[^,]*/ed=/' | TERMINFO=~/.zsh-terminfo tic -x -
```

Then, you can start `zsh` with:

```
TERMINFO=~/.zsh-terminfo zsh
```

And `unset TERMINFO` later, but you'll find that the completion is never cleared which makes it awkward to use.

Comment: @illuminÉ Try `/dev/stdin` instead of `-`, or use a temp file.

Comment: Ok, so I succeeded with `infocmp | sed 's/ed=[^,]*/ed=/' > testi && TERMINFO=~/.zsh-terminfo tic testi`. The result was further hidden from me because this created a xterm file whereas I had set $TERM to xterm-256color so just made a copy to that. I don't know why it's so hard to pipe stuff to `tic`, but anyways, that works!! Plus I had always wondered how you could alter the terminfo caps specs individually so your answer is so insightful... Thank you!

Comment: There is a tiny side effect in my case which is that if I do command completion, the prompt becomes invisible and appears one tab stop forward. In that case pressing tab makes it reappear... maybe just completion config I have in .zshrc. The tput cup 1 command is something I used in a graphic pattern rendering script I've explored before, so awkward won't be any surprise here :)